# how to sync files from mysql hosting site to google drive

Tags: mysql, google-drive-api

We are creating a web application using MySQL as our database, is there a way that some files from the hosting site of our application can be sync to the user's google drive?

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way of synchronizing your local data with Drive.

However, you can pseudo-sync with little load on your server by using [Changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes). Basically, you can get list of file changes since the time you specify. If I were you, I make a cron job of checking file changes from Drive and [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) specific files that have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what JunYoung Gwak suggests -> to ask google by polling them you will also have to keep a last edited date in your app and there might be cases when the local file is newer. will have to keep the same time zone as google to make it work for <24 hour changes.

So both sides will need to have a give changes since -date-time-in-timezone and a way to take a file for one place and update to the other.

Might have conflicts that need to be resolved by a diff tool.